# CSS float arbitrarily wrapping non-quirks mode despite having room

Tags: css, css-float

I have come across a weird problem where floated elements wrap to the next line when there is still plenty of space for them.
I realize this can be solved by removing the < p > or the < div > but I want clean valid code.
Most importantly I want to know why this is happening.

HTML:

```
<div class="section" style="width: 8000px;">
    <div style="" class="bottom">
        <div class="img6"></div>
        <p class="n">
        <a href="index.html" class="b t1"></a>
        <a href="a.html" class="b t2"></a>
        <a href="ab.html" class="b t3"></a>
        <a href="abc.html" class="b t4"></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p.n{margin:0;}
div.section{width: 8000px;}
div.section:after{content:"";display:block;clear:left;}
div.section div{float:left;}
a.b{display:block;float:left;}
div.img6{background:#933;width:78px;height:15px;}
a.t1{background:#123;width:74px;height:15px;}
a.t2{background:#456;width:86px;height:15px;}
a.t3{background:#555;width:92px;height:15px;}
a.t4{background:#786;width:126px;height:15px;}
```

Or you can see it [here at JSbin](http://jsbin.com/idenef/)

One interesting thing worth noting is that no matter how many elements you add only the last one is wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the `p` is not floated left. If you inspect the elements with for example firebug, you will see that the wrapper `div.bottom` has the exact width of it´s largest, unfloated, block level element, `p.n`, 378px.

If you float `p.n` as well, your problem is solved.

Comment: thank you. I didn't understand float widths before this helps a lot.                                                        For anyone reading this I have found: [http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floating the .bottom div left reduces its width and therefore everything it contains. Try changing `div.section div {float: left}` to `div.bottom div {float:left}`.

If you need to float everything, consider floating the external content right and/or specify fixed widths.

Comment: Sorry, but what I put up here is a simplified example my real page has a structure of:
div.section
  [floating stuff]
  div.top
  div.bottom

Mostly I want to know what is the reason the bottom div is reducing its width as this seems to be completely illogical as without the <p> it works fine